# Email verification failing before link is sent to email

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to createUserWithEmailAndPassword using firebase, I have done all needed and I see the user being created in firebase authenticate alright. I have added email verification to it where link is sent to the said email for verification but then even before I receive the email, the console logs "Email verification failed" Yes, I asked for that from a conditional statement.
const signUp = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Send email verification
    sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user)
      .then(() => {
        setVerificationPrompt('Check your email for verification');
        // Navigate to login only if email verification was successful
        if (userCredential.user.emailVerified) {
          navigate('/login');
        } else {
          console.log('Email verification failed');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending email verification:', error);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating user:', error);
  });
```

};

Email verification, accurate email verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sending** a verification email does not immediately set the `emailVerified` property to true. That only happens when the user **clicks** the link in that email.

So you'll need to wait until the user has clicked the link, then refresh their sign-in credentials (by either signing in again, or [calling `reload`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload)), and only **then** will the `emailVerified` property be true.

Comment: got it
Thanks 
Also, have you three firebase authentication with phone number before? Seems there's no user creation for that.